# How to show and hide when dismissed the soft keyboard in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom `DialogFragment` with a single input text in it, when the dialog is shown i would have the keyboard to be shown and when the done button is pressed or the positive button is pressed or the dialog is dismissed to hide that keyboard.

I have tried to show the keyboard as the following:

```
private fun showKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view?.findViewById(R.id.quantity), 0)
}
```

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    showKeyboard()
}
```

and to hide it in this way:

```
private fun closeKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view?.windowToken, 0)
}
```

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    closeKeyboard()
}
```

But the keyboard is not shown and if i focus on the input and try to dismiss the dialog the keyboard remains up.

Comment: We can call `closeKeyboard()` in onDestroyView and call `closeKeyboard()` before super.onDestroyView to dismiss the keyboard

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed I've tried to move it to onDestroyView but nothing, the keyboard remains still visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by setting the `isCancelable` to `false` as I couldn't hide the keyboard on overlay click. I managed to use the function `hideKeyboard()` in every action that dismissed the dialog, so the positive and negative buttons and the editor action when it's equal to `IME_ACTION_DONE`.

While to show the keyboard when the dialog is shown I've added this code:

```
 dialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
```

So here is the code of my DialogFragment:

```
private fun hideKeyboard() {
    val im: InputMethodManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(quantity.windowToken, 0)
}

private lateinit var quantity: EditText

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return activity?.let {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_quantity_input, null)

        isCancelable = false
        quantity = view.findViewById(R.id.quantity)

        builder.setView(view)

        viewModel.selectedProduct.value.let {
            quantity.setText(it?.quantity.toString())
        }

        builder.setTitle("Modifica quantità")

        builder.setPositiveButton("Conferma") { _, _ ->
            ...
            hideKeyboard()
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton("Annulla") { _, _ ->
            hideKeyboard()
        }

        quantity.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, _ ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                ...
                hideKeyboard()
                dismiss()
            }
            false
        }

        quantity.requestFocus()

        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)

        return dialog
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
}
```